# Incorrect Syntax Near "@Price"

Tags: c#, sqlclient

I have the following code in an event handler to add a product to my database based on data input by the user into a form.

```cs
private void btnquickadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand addproduct = new SqlCommand();
    addproduct.CommandText = "insert into [Products] values (@Product_name,@Description,@Stock,@Price";
    addproduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Name", txtquickaddproduct.Text);
    addproduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtquickadddescription.Text);
    addproduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stock", txtquickaddquantity.Text);
    addproduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", txtquickaddprice.Text);
    int execute = addproduct.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (execute>0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Product Added");
    }
}
```

The connection is configured correctly, but as shown in the photo, when the command is executed I get a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlExeception` saying my syntax is incorrect.

[image: 1]

What am I doing wrong or how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Closing bracket is missing after @Price

Comment: oh wow, cant beleive i missed that, its always the simplest things eh, haha..

Comment: I added your code as part of the post. You can click the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68537654/edit) button at the bottom to see how it's formatted now, or click on the "edited xxx time ago" link to see the [Revision History](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68537654/revisions) if you want to compare the difference.

Comment: I hope you are not caching your connection object, you need to dispose it and the command as soon as you're done, use a `using` block

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the closing `)` after `@Price`.

Comment: yeah i cant beleive i missed that, haha.. it does however result in a new issue of 

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.'

which im now looking into solving

Comment: If you have more columns than the ones listed in your query (likely an autogenerated ID column?), you will need to specify which columns the values you provided should be applied to. [The first example here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) shows the specification: `INSERT INTO [Table] ([Column1], [Column2]) VALUES (@Value1, @Value2)`.

Comment: That was exactly right, yeah an autogenerated ID i purposely left out thinking it would automatically be added, done sa you said and its now working perfectly.. thank you very much